# Activities to Distract from Stimming

Tags: toddler, autism, sensory

I have a 18 months toddler who has been put at risk of ASD. He has certain stimming behaviors and I am looking for distracting activities that can help him outgrow these.

I read that stimming happens due to some sensory overload or underload and appropriate activities for a given type of stimming can help control it (at least to some extent). We are about to start therapies but looking for some suggestions so that we cam engage with him in the right way.

His stimming behaviors are following:

1. Opening and closing doors
2. Spinning
3. Stamping right foot hard on floor
4. Flapping fingers near eyes/nose
5. Staring at spinning things (table fan/spinnig toys)
6. Switch on off
7. Turning pages of books back and forth
8. Making noises like Papapapa, etc.

Please share about what activities can be done against each of such behaviors (about whichever you know).

Comment: What's your motivation for this question? Does his behavior  scare/worry/annoy you? Other? It's very likely you have stimming behavior without realizing it, and might feel personally rejected if you were "corrected" each time you engaged in them. A toddler can't verbalize, "Your numerous corrections make me feel I'm unacceptable,"; that doesn't mean they don't feel that way.  (May I suggest that, while waiting for an answer, you do a google search for *behavioral interventions for "stimming" behaviors toddlers ASD*?)

Comment: I am voting to close this question as "needs more focus" only because you're asking for specifics about too many behaviors (i.e. focus on the worst first)? It's *not* because it's  a bad question; your question is fine. Many parents have experienced this and helpful suggestions would be great!

Comment: Oh, btw, I'm not on the spectrum, and I'm not neuroatypical (I don't *think* so, anyway!) I have some stimming behaviors myself, a couple that I'm not fond of,  yet can't seem to give up. Thankfully, no one is telling me to stop. I'm not sure how I would feel if someone did comment every time; I think I'd be annoyed at some point. If I got a nice, deep massage everyday as a trade off, I'd try it in a heartbeat. :)

Comment: My motivation is to know about activities that parents of autistic children might know from their experience. My son has been put at risk of ASD so naturally motivation comes from worry (its disappointing to see you couldn't get from the question and mentioning that it can be because I get annoyed). Your further remarks about he can't verbalize is even more shallow. I am his father and last thing I'll do so to make him feel rejected. Your another comment seem to undermine this matter ("Oh, btw, I'm not autistic") to the point that it seems you don't take autism seriously.

Comment: If you think question is asking a lot of things then just make that suggestion. Don't trivialize what you probably don't understand.  And yes I googled a lot before posting the question here. I come to stack exchange only when I am unable to find things on Google. Never in my experience though I have got such shallow, immature comments.

Comment: @Dayne Please understand the comments here are meant to help you get a useful answer, not to attack you. However, this question is too broad right now - questions here are meant to be reasonably limited in scope, in order to get a good answer that fits in the relatively small space allotted.  I think what you're eliding over here from Anongoodnurse's comments is that stimming is natural and harmless for the most part: it's not something to 'do' anything about.   Anongoodnurse's final comment was focused on that: stimming is something everyone does, on the spectrum or not.

Comment: The question we have for you is: are there things he's doing that are problematic, as in, dangerous, so extreme that they're causing discomfort in others, etc.; or are they just things that help him cope.  If there are behaviors that are causing problems, then focus on those - and probably on just *one* of those, because the answer will be different for each to some extent, unless they're very similar actions.

Comment: The other possible framing of the question that might be appropriate would be, *should I distract him from stimming* - in which case I suspect you would get good answers (but, different from what you've asked).  If you can focus on one of those two alternatives - either focus on a single activity and explain why it's a problem, or ask whether it's appropriate to distract him from these actions generally - I think you'll get some great answers.

Comment: On searching (Google/Google Scholar), I found a lot about stimming, most of it explaining why kids with ASD do it, and **some very good articles about not trying to change benign behaviors.** So, counter behaviors which might compromise someone's safety or social acceptability. Please be kinder in your comments. I didn't attack your character and don't appreciate you attacking mine. I take ASD seriously, and think that an answer would be very useful. I pointed out that neurotypical people do it, and lastly, since it was very subtle: deep pressure helps.

Comment: Thanks for serious comments this time. To distract this was recommended by his developmental pediatrician. secondly, I read articles as well. In all what I read they were suggestive that stimming should not be *stopped* but rather toddler should be **distracted** to something more meaningful and learning activity. Hence the question. I appreciate the comment on not focussed question but others I still think lacked maturity. Thirdly, I didn't say i want to stop stimming. We want to engage him in the right way with us. Anyway hopefully in therapies I might get more focussed answer.

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, no "distracting" activities will help him "outgrow" what is potentially ASD. If your son has ASD, he will not outgrow it. You need to know that no matter what you do it is not your fault or under your control whether your child is on the spectrum, but as a parent you can help accommodate your child to help him navigate the world. (Like all parents)

Rather than discourage you child from participating in stimming, focus on two things:

1. Appropriate stimming: If it is bothersome and disruptive for you son to open/close doors constantly, try giving him Play-Doh, a toy push button, a fidget-spinner, or some other toy that offer repetitive behavior without being as interruptive. Experiment with different types of toys to find which ones work best for you son. Consider that behavior like turning pages of books doesn't bother anyone, and is not destructive or distracting. Consider this type of stimming "acceptable"
2. Positive reinforcement: Encourage your child positively to participate in appropriate stimming. Rather than punish your child for stimming, reward your child with praise when he participates in positive stimming.

In my experience this is what has worked best from me. Your son is still young, and I hope you get your official diagnosis soon so you can move forward with him!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We did try some toys and they did help. Will try play-doh also as you suggested. I know he may not outgrow them but since his pediatrician suggested we have been trying to distract and engage him. Thanks again